# Why does grails-2.0.1 fail to create User, Role and UserRole domain objects in the BootStrap class init method?

Tags: grails, bootstrapping

*Hi, I am new to the Grails platform...*

I could create the User, Role and UserRole domain objects in the BootStrap class init method in the grails-1.3.7 version with the Spring Security Core Plugin ... But can not do the same in the grails-2.0.1 version..

Following is the code that I'm trying to execute ...

```
import com.beshto.Role
import com.beshto.User
import com.beshto.UserRole
import grails.util.Environment

class BootStrap {

  def init = {  servletContext ->
    switch (Environment.current) {
      case Environment.DEVELOPMENT:
        createInitialUsersIfRequired()
        break;
      case Environment.PRODUCTION:
        println "No special config or Bootstrapping required for the Production version..."
        break;
    }
  }

  def destroy = {
  }

  void createInitialUsersIfRequired() {
    println "Creating special config / Bootstrapping for Development version admin/4321 and user/1234..."

    if(Role.list().size() == 0) {
      new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true)
      new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(flush: true)
    }

    if(User.count() == 0){
      def newAdmin = new User(username: 'admin', enabled: true, password: '4321').save(flush: true)
      def newUser = new User(username: 'user', enabled: true, password: '1234').save(flush: true)

      UserRole.create newAdmin, Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN'), true
      UserRole.create newUser, Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER'), true

      assert User.count() == 2
      assert Role.count() == 2
    }
  }
}
```

Any HELP will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Changing: `.save(flush: true)` to `.save(flush: true, failOnError:true)` will cause you to get a stacktrace if the Domain Object doesn't pass validation.  I doubt this is the problem since it worked in 1.3.7 but it might be worth a look.

Comment: You have run `grails s2-quickstart com.beshto User Role UserRole` after installing the plugin haven't you?

Comment: @tim_yates I think he'd get a compilation error if he'd forgotten that because the classes are imported

Comment: @Don yeah, but it's always worth asking when people are so (seemingly purposefully) obtuse in their questions

Comment: SORRY for the delay... and it was not purposefully obtuse here.. May be I lack the clear expression skills like you  :-(... Don, thanks for pointing out .. yes, I ran the s2-quickstart.. @Jarred Olsen, Thanks very much for the tip... Error Message: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'com.beshto.User' on field 'profile': rejected value [null]... But this doesn't occur in the grails-1.3.7 .. i.e. the hibernate-plugin-1.3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check role creation method. Try to change:

`new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true)`

for

`new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(failOnError: true)`

And the same case for the users. For example:

```
new User(username: 'admin', enabled: true, password: '4321').save(failOnError: true)
```

instead of

```
new User(username: 'admin', enabled: true, password: '4321').save(flush: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same problem and played with it until it worked.

I am not 100% percent sure which change made it work, but here is what I did:

1. Changed quotations to be double quotations, so " instead of '.
   username: 'admin' would be username: "admin"

I thought maybe this was causing some java issues. I am not sure.

Check that your user and role are actually saved! Add fail on error as they recommended above.

Then go to your User, Role, and UserRole classes and make sure that every variable that you have defined is actually being set. Even if you don't have any constraints, if you have a string, just assign it "" the empty string. The reason may be that while it can accept blank strings, it may not accept null strings.

This was what solved it for me. It was very hard to solve because there was no valuable output from the terminal and I had to think of different things.

I hope this solves your issue. It's probably related to saving with constraints on fields of an object not being satisfied.

Let me know if it doesn't work and try to provide more information.

Good luck!