# Grails Spring Security BootStrap

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I am on `Grails 2.1.1` and `Spring Security Core Plugin 1.2.7.3`.

I am trying to assign Roles to Users in `BootStrap.groovy` and persist these assignments.  I create my Roles and an Admin User in BootStrap.

I found the following blog post: [Create User Roles for Spring Security](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/03/create-userroles-for-spring-security.html)

When I try this approach, I get:

> 2012-09-16 22:00:56,762 ERROR [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader] Error executing bootstraps:
>
> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: User.addToAuthorities() is applicable for argument types: (Role) values: Possible solutions: getAuthorities()

I also tried

```
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        ....
        admin.getAuthorities().add(adminRole) 
        admin.save(flush: true)
        ....
    }
}
```

However, when I checked the `user_role` table, it was empty (I checked and entries for Admin User and Admin Role were in respective user and role tables, just not the association).

Could anyone please provide me some guidance or insight on what I am doing wrong?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Seems a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501934/why-does-grails-2-0-1-fail-to-create-user-role-and-userrole-domain-objects-in-t

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That blog post is 3 years old and wrong for the current plugin in two ways. One, don't encode the password, it's done for you in the User class. And two (the problem you're seeing now) don't call collections methods (addTo, removeFrom) because collections aren't used. Call `UserRole.create admin, adminRole` as described in the plugin docs: http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/index.html (in particular the tutorial in section 23.1).